# Replace "." with "_" Golang

Tags: regex, go, regexp-replace

been doing Go programming on Codewars as a hobby and stumbled upon following task:

*The code provided is supposed to replace all the dots . in the specified String with dashes -
But it's not working properly.
Task: Fix the bug so we can all go home early.*

Initial wrong code:

```
regexp.MustCompile(`.`).ReplaceAllString(str, "-")
```

Through brute force, i've made it work like this:

```
regexp.MustCompile(`[.]`).ReplaceAllString(str, "-")
```

The correct answer is apparently this:

```
regexp.MustCompile(`\.`).ReplaceAllString(str, "-")
```

Could someone please explain the logic behind my solution and the right one.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The dot is a metacharactere. It matches single character. To use it as a real dot, you have to escape it with \

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct too.

In regex, the dot define a [special metacharacter](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) but inside a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) it's a regular dot.

It is possible however to complain about the misleading impression of metacharacter use, so the escaped dot is more clear and easy to understand.